# PHP mktime with daylight savings and other variables

Tags: php, timezone, dst

I use mktime() to store all of my dates for everything in my database, and I have a script that goes through and returns dates for set amounts of times, this works fine for showing how long ago things were posted, however when I try to return the exact date/time it returns one hour ahead of time, so I'm wondering how to get the date to always return the correct date when the time gets changed for any daylight savings or anything.

Here's basically what I use (cut down to only show small portion of it):

```
function time_stamp($session_time) 
{ 
    date_default_timezone_set("EST");

    $time_difference = time() - $session_time; 

    $seconds = $time_difference; 
    $minutes = round($time_difference / 60 );
    $hours = round($time_difference / 3600 ); 
    $days = round($time_difference / 86400 ); 
    $weeks = round($time_difference / 604800 ); 
    $months = round($time_difference / 2419200 ); 
    $years = round($time_difference / 29030400 );

    // Seconds
    if($seconds==0)
    {
         return $seconds." second ago";     //See this works fine, obviously
    }
        else if($seconds <=60&&$seconds>0)
    {
        return date('F jS \a\t g:ia ', $session_time+60*60); //it's when i use date()
                                                             //it doesn't
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution...

Add this one line in your php.ini file:

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

After doing this, there is no need for:

```
date_default_timezone_set("EST");
```

And using functions like:

```
time();
```

Or

```
date();
```

Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you know if there are simple solutions to get the time to be correct worldwide? It seems like in order to do that you might need multiple scripts and all of that.

Comment: The library I just reffered to does not compensate for all daylight saving events. Explicitly mentioned in the PHP manual oddball territories like islands are not included in the class. However, most major cities and countries ARE INCLUDED. So if you are using this to fix world scale I would say you are 99% covered.

Comment: Ok, and thanks however my php ini file already has this line.

Comment: **DO** store all of your times in UTC and then convert them to the appropriate timezone. **DON'T** try to work it out yourself.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set("EST"); will overwrite date.timezone = "America/New_York". Just use date.timezone = "America/New_York".

Comment: Well even once I remove those it doesn't change any.

Comment: Do you run your own server or are you using web hosting?